# Campo que só permita uma quantidade exata de dados

Tags: mysql

Como colocar um campo no mysql que só permita somente 4 caracteres. Nem mais e nem menos?

Estou fazendo assim:

> alter table cartoes add os_4_ultimos_digitos int (4); <

Mas é necessário uma constraint e não consigo fazer.

Comment: É varchar o campo?

Comment: @rray Conforme coloquei na pergunta: alter table cartoes add os_4_ultimos_digitos int (4); <

Comment: Você quer 4 caracteres com zero a esquerda ou sem? `ALTER TABLE cartoes ADD CHECK ( os_4_ultimos_digitos > 999 )` obriga de 1000 pra cima. Se quer 4 digitos com zero à esquerda, é caso de habilitar o _zerofill_ do campo.

Comment: @Bacco pode ser com 0 a esquerda por que os 4 últios número dum cartão pode começar com 0.

Comment: @AndréNascimento então basta você ligar o zerofill do MySQL que já vem preenchido. Mas eu acho que o lugar certo de tratar disso é na aplicação, e não no DB.

Answer (score 3):

Para preencher um valor INT com zeros à esquerda:

```
ALTER
   TABLE cartoes
CHANGE
   COLUMN `os_4_ultimos_digitos`
   `os_4_ultimos_digitos` INT(4) ZEROFILL
```

Para adicionar uma coluna já com esta característica:

```
ALTER
   TABLE cartoes
ADD
   os_4_ultimos_digitos INT(4) ZEROFILL;
```

### Alternativa com TRIGGER

Caso prefira, pode usar um campo VARCHAR, e forçar o DB a não aceitar nada diferente de 4 caracteres ao inserir com um *trigger*:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER trg_len_4_insert BEFORE INSERT ON cartao
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE msg VARCHAR(255);
    IF LENGTH( new.os_4_ultimos_digitos ) != 4 THEN
        SET msg = concat( 'Erro: tamanho errado do campo: ', CAST(new.os_4_ultimos_digitos AS CHAR) );
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET message_text = msg;
    END IF;
END
DELIMITER ;
```

Veja esse código funcionando aqui: **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/551e6)**.

Crie um para BEFORE UPDATE também, se for o caso

**Notas:**

- Esta sintaxe é válida para MySQL 5.5 ou maior
- Mais opções [nesta postagem do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24).

### Recomendação

Postei as alternativas acima para responder à pergunta com a tag MySQL, mas se está usando alguma outra linguagem para a aplicação, o lugar mais adequado para se tratar isso é na aplicação, e não na estrutura do DB.

Você pode manter o INT como está, e tratar dos dados no momento em que o usuário preencher os dados, e ao recuperar os mesmos do DB, fazer o *padding* adequadamente (que aliás, é a alternativa mais simples).

Comment: Jurava que o MySQL não tinha o recurso de check constraints!

Comment: @renatoargh O MySQL "tem mas não funciona". Adaptei a resposta, grato pelo alerta. Fazer sem testar é complicado, dessa vez eu fiz um _fiddle_ para ver se não é propaganda enganosa :)

Answer (score 1):

Se o campo for novo:

```
ALTER TABLE cartoes 
ADD COLUMN os_4_ultimos_digitos CHAR(4);
```

campo existente:

```
ALTER TABLE cartoes
CHANGE COLUMN os_4_ultimos_digitos CHAR(4);
```

tenta reduzir o nome desse campo, está estranho

Comment: Achei perfeito o nome. O que você sugeriria, @Marcelo?

Comment: Se está perfeito para você é o que importa :)  eu costumo por campos mais enxutos e que remetem a qualidade do valor que vai alocar... Ex: digito_verificador já na tela você coloca o nome mais familiar ao usuário.

Comment: digito_verificador também está ótimo. Eu pensei que você diria que faria algo como 4_ult_dig . Aí eu teria que respeitosamente discordar, rs.

Comment: @Marcelo Bonus talvez o nome do campo seria: nr_4_ultimos ou nr_ultimos quem está desenvolvendo sabe o nome, mas as vezes, por não segui uma lógica fácio de se entender, alguns programadores colocam nomes abreviados e eu nõa gosto disso. Por exemplo: nome "nm", coisas do tipo. Prefiro colocar dois nomes inteiros do que várias abreviaturas.

Comment: @Marcelo Bonus seus comandos dml permitem dados menores que 4 dígitos. O int (4) permite de 1 a 4 algarismos e não é o que eu quero. Eu quero somente 4 dígitos, nem mais nem menos. Por exemplo, final de cartão 3579, se eu pegar o número anterior para formar 5 dígitos, não aceita no sistema ou se eu só informar 3 dos 4 dígitos, também não validar.

Comment: Entendo, coloca tipo char no lugar de int

Comment: Mas voce deve fazer uma verificaçao do tamanho do campo no seu formulario para evitar uma chamada ao servidor